# Update blob image in Database with UPDATE MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, blob

I am trying to update a record in my database which is a blob type, I can insert using this method really easily but when using UPDATE it doesn't seem to work, only for text. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","plantidentify");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$ufamid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ufamilyid']);
$ucommonname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ucomname']);
$usynname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['usynonyms']);
$uspecies = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uspecies']);
$uprop = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['upropagation']);
$uimageData = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, (file_get_contents($_FILES['uimage']['tmp_name'])));
$uheight = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uheight']);
$utreeclass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['utreeclass']);
$ulifecycle = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ulifecycle']);

$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE plant 
                SET FamilyID='$ufamid', CommonName='$ucommonname',       
                    SynonymNames='$usynname', Species='$uspecies', 
                    Propagation='$uprop', Image='$uimageData', 
                    Height='$uheight', TreeClass='$utreeclass', 
                    Lifecycle='$ulifecycle' 
                WHERE PlantID='$_POST[uplantid]'";


if (!mysqli_query($conn,$UpdateQuery)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}

header("Location: plantedit.php");

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

$uimageData is the variable in which contains the uploaded file from my form in another file. The column in my database where I am trying to update the blob is called "Image".

This might help, here is the form code that is in another .php which the update plant.php gets fired from:

```
    <?php //display databse values
        while($plant=mysql_fetch_array($retval)) {
        echo"<form action=updateplant.php method=post>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=number name=ufamilyid value='" .$plant['FamilyID']."' ></td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=ucomname value='" .$plant['CommonName']."' ></td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=usynname value='" .$plant['SynonymNames']."' ></td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=uspecies value='" .$plant['Species']."' ></td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=uprop value='" .$plant['Propagation']."' ></td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=file name=uimage></td>";
        echo "<td>" . '<img class="crop2" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode( $plant['Image'] ).'"/>'." </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=number name=uheight value='" .$plant['Height']."' ></td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=utreeclass value='" .$plant['TreeClass']."' ></td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=ulifecycle value='" .$plant['Lifecycle']."' ></td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=uplantid value='" .$plant['PlantID']."' ></td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=Update" . " ></td>";
        echo "</tr>";




        echo "</form>";
        }//end while
        mysql_close($conn);
        ?>
```

Comment: No, no MySQL errors what so ever. I also ran my code in a PHP Validator but all is okay. I am really stuck here.

Comment: ok  .can you echo $UpdateQuery on browser and run it on phpmyadmin

Comment: Try to remove redirect and then to watch for errors. And also are you sure you making a POST request? Your code does not check if there any data came with the request.

Comment: Also inside double-quoted string, array reference should be wrapped like that: `{$_POST['uplantid']}`. And it sould not be put unescaped inside the query.

Comment: I echoed the $UpdateQuery and this is the out put: UPDATE plant SET FamilyID='3', CommonName='Cape Edelweiss', SynonymNames='', Species='L. lanata', Propagation='', Image='', Height='1', TreeClass='', Lifecycle='Annual' WHERE PlantID='6'

Comment: It seems like there is no image? Even though I have selected one.

Comment: @SourceCoder if you remove the `Image`, does it work?

Comment: I removed the redirect and still no errors. I am definitely making a POST request. I also changed my code to :   {$_POST['uplantid']} as you stated, still no change.

Comment: @baldrs do you mean if I just have my Variable there? Or remove the entire thing completely? The rest of the UPDATE works regardless of whether Image='$uimageData', is there or not. But if I just take away the "Image" then no, I get an error.

Comment: Please check whether you are recieving anything on $uimageData = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, (file_get_contents($_FILES['uimage']['tmp_name']))); . Also  post your html here

Comment: @baldrs I just updated the main post with the code of my form if that helps?

Comment: If you want to upload files, your form must have an `enctype` attribute: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: @Anish I just did check and it seems as though I am not receiving anything as the previous echo made clear, I have also updated the main post with my form code, perhaps the error lies in that?

Comment: @SourceCoder your image is not going to be uploaded because of your form tag lacks what I have written above.

Comment: @baldrs, Thank you thank you thank you so much! I can't believe I overlooked that! Thank you again it's much appreciated.

Comment: @Anish, thank you for all your input Anish, Baldrs has resolved my problem. Thank you both!

Comment: @SourceCoder so you are welcome, though now please accept the answer that resolves your problem and vote it up. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to upload a file you should mention      `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in form  . Hope this will fix your problem.

```
<?php 

//display databse values
            while($plant=mysql_fetch_array($retval)) {
            echo"<form action='updateplant.php' method='post'  enctype='multipart/form-data' >";

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=number name=ufamilyid value='" .$plant['FamilyID']."' ></td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=ucomname value='" .$plant['CommonName']."' ></td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=usynname value='" .$plant['SynonymNames']."' ></td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=uspecies value='" .$plant['Species']."' ></td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=uprop value='" .$plant['Propagation']."' ></td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=file name=uimage></td>";
            echo "<td>" . '<img class="crop2" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode( $plant['Image'] ).'"/>'." </td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=number name=uheight value='" .$plant['Height']."' ></td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=utreeclass value='" .$plant['TreeClass']."' ></td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=ulifecycle value='" .$plant['Lifecycle']."' ></td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=uplantid value='" .$plant['PlantID']."' ></td>";
            echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=Update" . " ></td>";
            echo "</tr>";




            echo "</form>";
            }//end while
            mysql_close($conn);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo in the `WHERE` statement, `$_POST[uplantid]` should be `". $_POST['uplantid'] ."`

Comment: I made the change with the typo that you stated but there was still no difference. The image still doesn't seem to UPDATE into the table of my database. Thank you for your input though.